# How do I provide inline error feedback with Laravel 4 and Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: php, validation, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I'm building a form using Laravel 4 and Twitter Bootstrap 3 and I want to error messages to appear next to the field.  This is the solution that I came up with but it ends up being 15 lines of code per field.

```
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Edit User</h1>

        {{ Form::model($user, array('route' => array('users.update', $user->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}

        {{-- First Name field --}}
        {{-- Start a form group. If there any errors, then highlight the field red. --}}
        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('first_name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            {{-- Display the label and the field. --}}
            {{ Form::label('first_name', 'First Name', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')) }}
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                {{ Form::text('first_name', NULL, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'First Name')) }}
            </div>
            {{-- If there is an error, display any messages to the right of the field with a warning icon. --}}
            @if($errors->has('first_name')) 
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    @foreach ($errors->get('first_name') as $message)
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> 
                            {{ $message }}
                        </span>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>

        {{-- Form buttons --}}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{-- Line up the buttons with the right edge of the fields. --}}
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    {{-- Cancel button takes user back to profile page. --}}
                    {{ HTML::linkRoute('users.show', 'Cancel', array($user->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
                    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{ Form::close() }}

    </div>
@stop
```

This is how it appears:
[image: Form screenshot]

I'm just starting out with both Laravel and Bootstap.  I used [Jeffery Way's tutorial on NetTuts](https://tutsplus.com/course/whats-new-in-laravel-4/) to make the form and [Coder's Guide's tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrtmSNlsE6U&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PLMvLDJ7usmZB-Mu4kNB-Qtr_1serQjfti) to apply the formatting.

Should I be using client-side validation or would this be considered an acceptable implementation of Laravel 4 and Bootstrap?

Thanks!

Comment: Really good question. I think ideally the Form class maybe via `Form::label()` could be extended but I don't know what the "proper" way would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may not be the coolest way to do this but I think it's pretty slick.

Laravel has a feature called `Form::macro` that allows you to sort of make reusable code snippets. You can define a macro all kinds of places but I just slapped mine in my `routes.php` file to get this going real quick.

```
Form::macro('errorMsg', function($field, $errors){
    if($errors->has($field)){
        $msg = $errors->first($field);
        return "<span class=\"error\">$msg</span>";
    }
    return '';
});
```

Then to use in a form, pass the macro your error messages:

```
{{ Form::label('first_name', 'First Name:') }}
{{ Form::text('first_name') }}
{{ Form::errorMsg('first_name', $errors) }}
{{-- where $errors is your Illuminate\Support\MessageBag object --}}
```

To get even more tech, you can use `Form::objects` in a `Form::macro` like so:

```
Form::macro('textError', function($field, $label, $errors){
    $label_html = Form::label($field, $label);
    $text_html = Form::text($field);
    $msg_html = '';

    if($errors->has($field)){
            $msg_html.= '<span class="error">';
            $msg_html.= $errors->first($field);
            $msg_html.= '</span>';
    }

    return $label_html.$text_html.$msg_html;
});
```

Then you're at `1` line per input:

```
{{ Form::textError('first_name', 'First Name:', $errors) }}
```

You'd need to make other macros for password, textarea, etc. (which is why I just use the first example; it's only a couple more lines of code per input and serves all input types.)

If you wanted to style your input on error, eg. a red border, you'd probably want the second example then wrap it in your `div.form-group` or whatevers. Anyway, options out the wazoo.

UPDATE: An even slicker way to get errors in macros is to access them via `Session::get('errors');` like so:

```
Form::macro('errorMsg', function($field){//yay! we don't have to pass $errors anymore
    $errors = Session::get('errors');

    if($errors && $errors->has($field)){//make sure $errors is not null
        $msg = $errors->first($field);
        return "<span class=\"error\">$msg</span>";
    }
    return '';
});
```

Comment: Thanks sudo! I ended up putting it in `app/start/global.php` but it worked perfectly.